# Is this enough to be differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $c \in (a,b)$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable for each $x \in (a,b) \setminus \{c\}$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f'(x)$ exists (from both sides) and is finite. Is it enough to claim that $f$ has to differentiable at $c$ also? If we drop the assumption that $f$ is continuous the answer is clearly negative (just take $f(c)=1$ and $0$ otherwise) but I don;t see how to construct a countexample if $f$ has to be continuous.
I would be grateful or any help

Comment: What about $y=|x|$ at 0?

Comment: Do you want the limit of the derivative to fully exist, or just to exist from each side separately?  If the latter, then Simplyorange's example suffices.

Comment: @Simplyorange the limit does not exist at 0

Comment: Oh I misunderstood OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the 'one sided' part of this is a standard and often asked for result. It follows from the mean value theorem (e.g. for $x>c$):
$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = f^\prime(\xi)  $$
for some $\xi\in (c, x)$ - now let $x\rightarrow c$ which then implies that the r.h.s of this equation converges (by assumption), which in turm implies one-sided differentiability in $c$.
If the limits for $x\rightarrow c$ of $f^\prime(x)$ don't coincide from the left and right then $f $ will not be differentiable, otherwise yes...

(Note that the mean value theorem only requires differentiability in the open interval $(c, x)$).

Comment: Thank you, indeed it works!